# Variable oscillator circuit breaking at certain resistances

Tags: oscillator, circuit-design, short-circuit

I'm trying to build an oscillator circuit using a schmitt inverter (74HC14). I've got the following schematic:

[image]

The plan is to control the frequency by varying the resistance using a 10k pot. I figure using the resistor/capacitor values listed I should be able to get a frequency range between 1.2 and ~200hz.

I've simulated the circuit using circuits.io, and everything goes well until I drop the pot to its lowest setting. At this point the sim shows the IC will exceed its current draw. It's running too fast for me to see by how much (the nature of the circuit means the break is intermittent), but I think it's around 53 mW at the time of death.

I presume this is due to the pot reaching 0 or near-0 resistance, but I'm not sure how to prevent it from shorting the circuit. If i hook up the third terminal to ground on the pot, I then see a break at either extreme of the resistance value.

How should I be limiting the current here?

Thanks,

Comment: Place a small resistance in series with the pot to ascertain a minimal resistance in the path which the IC can handle?

Comment: Tried a series connector?

Comment: Simply increase R4 until this effect stops.

Answer (score 1):

Increase r4 to a point where the max current (usually 20ma) isn't exceeded. 220r typically works.

Answer (score 0):

Arsenal was correct, adding a 1k resistor in series with the pot has fixed the problem.

Comment: @user2943160 Actually, It's _Arsenal_ who did not provide an answer to the question. He chose to answer in a comment, which can not be accepted as an answer, and apparently he's not alone.

Comment: @pipe: that was an auto-comment due to me improperly reviewing the answer. While the answer has much that could be improved, it is a solution to the proposed question.

Comment: @user2943160 I see, yes, I most certainly agree that this answer can be improved..